# Book about a man that is duplicated in a booth

Tags: story-identification, books

A man is duplicated six times in a booth, but the process is not acurate, as the duplicates are not exact, but depend of how each of the persons connected to the booth percieve him. He has to go to Venus to stop the asteroid bombardments from there, where a man who has a special kind of cancer that keeps him alive for a very long time as it overgrows him.

Comment: I can't help but feel that the last sentence was not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an unusual sensation for me. I immediately recognized the book from your description of the plot -- even though I've never read it myself!

***[The Duplicated Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?250467)*** was co-authored by **James Blish** and **Robert Lowndes**. Lowndes apparently used the pen name of "Michael Sherman" when this novel was first published within the pages of the magazine *Dynamic Science Fiction* (August, 1953). But it seems that subsequent reprints of the material, in book editions, always mentioned his real name on the cover.

[image]

I remembered something about the plot of this book because several years ago I bought a copy of ***[Takeoff Too](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34231)***, a collection of miscellaneous odds and ends written by Randall Garrett, which includes within its pages a reprint of something he wrote after *The Duplicated Man* was released in magazine format (but before its first book edition came out in 1959). He titled it:

[**"James Blish and Michael Sherman's 'The Duplicated Man' : A Review in Verse"**](https://ia801304.us.archive.org/5/items/Future_Science_Fiction_29_1956/Future_Science_Fiction_29_1956.pdf)

(If you follow that link, it will take you to a PDF of the magazine in which the review-poem was first published. Scroll down to Page 112 in the PDF, and you'll see the start of the review, which retells the entire plot in rhyming quatrains.)

Garrett's retelling of the plot strongly resembles your summary, including brief mention of a bad guy, based on Venus, having cancer which somehow is not killing him off the way you'd expect. Also, regarding the multiple duplication of the hero (Paul Danton), Garrett says:

```
The machine gives a pop and a buzz, un-
Derlined by a couple of clicks.
Five new ones -- almost half a dozen. 
With Danton himself, that makes six.

One duplicate's killed by the Party;
Two more leave the Earth, Venus bound,
While the other two, still hale and hearty,
Decided they will stay on the ground.
```

In addition, here's the entire "Plot Summary" from [the novel's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Duplicated_Man):

> At war with Venus for decades, the Earth's military authority stood
> its ground. Missiles kept raining down on Earth with unpredictable
> regularity. Nobody knew where the next missile would hit. But
> conventional wisdom dictated that every attack be met with a
> counter-attack.
>
> However, a pacifist peace party sought to have a truce declared with
> Venus. Paul Danton, a member of a subversive political party, who
> believed in peace so be his answer to make peace was considered.
>
> It was a peculiar stroke of luck that he found a human duplication
> machine. It was an old machine, and it didn't work reliably after the
> first five copies were made. But if he could just duplicate the right
> world leaders, essentially make extra copies of them, maybe he would
> have a chance bringing peace to Earth and Venus.

So you can see why I feel confident that this is the novel you are remembering, even though I've never perused a single page of the text.

Comment: The magazine version is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Dynamic_Science_Fiction_v01n04_1953-08_cape1736).

Comment: Thanks, this is it, how do i mark this as the correct answer? Edit - Found it and set it as the correct answer, Thank a lot, it has been bugging me for quite a few months now

Comment: Interesting. I have this book - bought it as a Blish complete-ist - but I've never read it all.  Now I will...this is why I like story id questions.

Comment: It's not that great a story anyway; I bet the poem review was much more readable than the book.